# not getting checkbox element value from form

Tags: laravel

I have a small form in Laravel 5.4 which has a checkbox and a text box. The issue is that when I post the form, the checkbox value is not coming through the request. I have custom styling on the checkbox but surely it can't be that?

I've been looking at this for a while, and everything looks normal. My code is below:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.settings.save') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><b>Site Name</b></label>
                <p>This is the name of your LaravelFileManager instance.</p>
                <input name="siteName" id="siteName" class="form-control" value="{{ \App\Helpers\ConfigHelper::getValue('site_name') }}" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label><b>Footer Message</b></label>
                <p>You can customise the footer message for the application.</p>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="showFooter" id="showFooter" checked="{{ \App\Helpers\ConfigHelper::getValue('show_footer_message') }}"> Show footer message
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Save Changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My controller code is as such:

```
public function saveSettings(Request $request) {
    $siteName = $request->input('siteName');
    $showFooter = $request->input('showFooter');

    ConfigHelper::setValue('site_name', $siteName);
    ConfigHelper::setValue('show_footer_message', $showFooter);

    return redirect()->route('admin.settings')->with('result', 'Settings saved.');
}
```

My route:

```
Route::post('settings/save', ['uses' => 'Admin\SettingsController@saveSettings'])->name('admin.settings.save');
```

I've also done a vardump on the $request variable and even that is missing the check box value:

```
array(2) { 
    ["_token"]=> string(40) "sgyO7Kkz1ljsYEZ1G5nkj4uVbmFZqiTMbpK9P6Bi" 
    ["siteName"]=> string(16) "File Manager 1.0" 
}
```

It's missing the 'showFooter' variable.

Not quite sure where to go with this one. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to set a value in your input type.

Comment: @Jenssen I've set a default `value=""` to the checkbox input, still crashes out

Comment: @MorganLane What I use is a ternary on the controller, like this: `request('showFooter') ? true : false` in that way if it is checked you will get `true` and if it's unchecked you get a `false`. Does that work with you?

Comment: Try **$request->get(''showFooter'')**

Comment: @Lvkz Done that, just comes up as false, even when the checkbox is checked :/

Comment: @OdinThunder That works, but only when it's checked. Putting it with Lvkz's answer fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got this working in the end. Using help from the comments:

```
public function saveSettings(Request $request) {
    $siteName = $request->input('siteName');
    $showFooter = $request->has('showFooter');

    ConfigHelper::setValue('site_name', $siteName);
    ConfigHelper::setValue('show_footer_message', $showFooter);

    return redirect()->route('admin.settings')->with('result', 'Settings saved.');
}
```

For some reason, using `$request->input('showFooter')` wasn't working properly. `$request->get('showFooter')` brings a result when true, so adding the ternary makes it work every time.

Comment: In this case better use  **$request->has('showFooter')**. This will return you true or false.